# Avoiding inadvertently copying objects - the techniques available

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, shared-ptr, pass-by-pointer

(There are three related questions here)

One of the nastiest things I encounter in C++ is accidentally passing/copying an object and then wondering why its state is not what you expect. I recently had a situation where I was passing by pointer, but I was not getting the state I expected and it turned out I had to pass the pointer by reference, which really threw me!

Can I just confirm given this situation:

```
MyClass x;
AnotherClass y;
y.passMyObjectSomewhere(x);
.
.
.
.
//Later on x is changed and I wish to see this change in y
x.modifyMyObject();
```

I have the following techniques available to keep the state of `x` updated in `y`:

```
MyClass* x = new MyClass();
y.passMyObjectSomewhere(x);
.
.
.
delete x;
```

or

```
MyClass x;
y.passMyObjectSomewhere(&x);
```

or

```
shared_ptr<MyClass> x(new MyClass());
y.passMyObjectSomewhere(x);
```

1) and all of the above alternatives will keep `x` updated in the `y` object, if I make changes to `x` outside of `y`?

---

2) Does the above change if x was an object to a vector or another STL collection? Or do the same rules apply?

---

3) What about a class where a pointer in the constructor is assigned to a data member:

```
class X{
    public:
        X(Something* x);

    private:
        Something* x;
}

X::X(Something* &y){
    x = y;
}
```

Would `y` have to be passed in by reference here because otherwise a copy of the pointer would be assigned? I ask this due to another SO question I asked here:

[Pointer to pointer assignment isnt working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871184/pointer-to-pointer-assignment-isnt-working)

Comment: declaration of `passMyObjectSomewhere`?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, they should if you store a pointer to your x. But be careful in your 2 first examples, `y` seems to be able to outlive `x`. The pointer in `y`won't know that the object pointed will be deleted and this will certainly cause a crash:

```
MyClass* x = new MyClass();
y.passMyObjectSomewhere(x);
.
// update x
y.doesSomeActionOnX(); // no crash
delete x;
y.doesSomeActionOnX(); // crash
```

The `std::shared_ptr` is a better option as it does handle ownership sharing. BTW you can do:

```
auto x = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
```

2) Same rules everywhere.

3) Your reference is totally useless here.

```
X::X(Something* y)
{ 
  this.y = y;
}
```

Comment: Regarding #3 did I mis-read something in the SO question I asked a few weeks ago (linked in my question here) then?

Comment: Your other question was the other way around you wanted to modify the pointer given as parameter.